C# WPF TreeView offsetting child position for consistent views?
Let's say I have a couple of items that look like this:
Layer 1
|-Layer 2
|-Layer 2
 |-Layer 3
  |-Layer 4
|-Layer 2

Without creating an empty parent, how would one go about to recreate something akin to:
Layer 1
  |-Layer 4
 |-Layer 3
|-Layer 2
|-Layer 2
  |-Layer 4
|-Layer 2
 |-Layer 3
  |-Layer 4

Is it even possible, or would invisible parents be needed to be created, thus resulting in a lot of empty spaces (since they would have no value what so ever). Basically, can treeview be made to look pretty to designate different layers, each layer having something in common and aligning with others of that commonality, regardless of position in the tree?
